# Chartingtoolkit: Pie series Changes Colors After Updating

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, observablecollection

I use a pie series chart to show the allocation of four values that I add to an ObervableCollection. Everything works fine, but when I update  the ObervableCollection the assignment of the colors changes (Update means that I clear the Collection and add new values, maybe that causes the problem. But there exists no Replace Method for OCs). I also definded standard colors for the pie series, what works, however the assignment changes.

This is how my pie series looks like when I fill the first values to the ObservableCollection that is binded to the chart:

[image]

After updating the ObservableCollection it looks like that:
[image]

As you can see the values are at the same positon. Only the colors that are assigned to the values have changed their position.

[image]

This is where I fill the ObservableCollection:
private ObservableCollection> _allocationList;

```
public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, int>> AllocationList
{
    get { return _allocationList; }
    set
    {
    _allocationList = value;
    OnPropertyChanged("AllocationList");
    }
}


if (AllocationList != null)
{
    ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, int>> TempAllocationList = CheckAllocation.GetAllocation(Value1List, Value2List, Value3List, Value4List);
    int temp1Value = TempAllocationList[0].Value + AllocationList[0].Value;
    int temp2Value = TempAllocationList[1].Value + AllocationList[1].Value;
    int temp3Value = TempAllocationList[2].Value + AllocationList[2].Value;
    int temp4Value = TempAllocationList[3].Value + AllocationList[3].Value;

    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
    {
        AllocationList.Clear();
        AllocationList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Value1", temp1Value));
        AllocationList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Value2", temp2Value));
        AllocationList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Value3", temp3Value));
        AllocationList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Value4", temp4Value));
    }));

}
else
{
    AllocationList = CheckAllocation.GetAllocation(Value1List, Value2List, Value3List, Value4List);
}
```

And this is the XAML I wrote:

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart>
   <chartingToolkit:PieSeries DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding AllocationList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
      <chartingToolkit:PieSeries.Palette>
         <visualizationToolkit:ResourceDictionaryCollection>
            <ResourceDictionary>
               <Style x:Key="DataPointStyle" TargetType="Control">
                  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
               </Style>
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary>
               <Style x:Key="DataPointStyle" TargetType="Control">
                  <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF045704"/>
               </Style>
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary>
               <Style x:Key="DataPointStyle" TargetType="Control">
                  <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF0AB60A"/>
               </Style>
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary>
              <Style x:Key="DataPointStyle" TargetType="Control">
                 <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF246E24"/>
              </Style>
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary>
              <Style x:Key="DataPointStyle" TargetType="Control">
                 <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF064006"/>
              </Style>
            </ResourceDictionary>
         </visualizationToolkit:ResourceDictionaryCollection>
     </chartingToolkit:PieSeries.Palette>
   </chartingToolkit:PieSeries >
</chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your guess is correct. This is a problem with the clear and re-add of the listitems. 
One Solution without clear would be to get the Index of Your Items and replace them with the Indexer:

```cs
    var pvI  = AllocationList.Select(x => x.Key).ToList().IndexOf("Photovoltaik");
    var pwkI = AllocationList.Select(x => x.Key).ToList().IndexOf("Windkraft");
    var bmvI = AllocationList.Select(x => x.Key).ToList().IndexOf("Biomasse");
    var wakI = AllocationList.Select(x => x.Key).ToList().IndexOf("Wasserkraft");

    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
    {
         AllocationList[pvI] = new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Photovoltaik", tempPVValue);
         AllocationList[pwkI] = new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Windkraft", tempWKValue);
         AllocationList[bmvI] = new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Biomasse", tempBMValue);
         AllocationList[wakI] = new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Wasserkraft", tempWaKValue);
    }));
```